# How can I use python dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I already made json secret file like this.

```
json_data = {

    'creon' :
            {'token' : ["abcd"]}}
```

So I want to use exactly like this.

```
token = app_info['creon']['token']
print(token)
> "abcd"
```

But, result is like this.

```
print(token)
> abcd
```

How can I use the way I wanted?

---

Last tried result)

```
import os
import json

app_info = os.getenv('App_info')
with open(app_info, 'r') as f:
  app_info = json.load(f)

token = '"'+app_info['creon']['token']+'"'
print(token)
```

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Comment: seems you want `token = json_data['creon']['token'][0]`? -

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken I tried but this error appears..

'TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I see couple of problems. First of all when you are doing it so, you are not getting a `string` values, but unicode `{u'creon': {u'token': [u'abcd']}}`, which can't work in you current situation. Now then you need to convert it to string when you get it like so `app_info['creon']['token'][0].encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')` and then you can print it properly.

I modified the code to look like this:

```py
import os
import json


app_info = os.getenv('App_info')
with open(app_info, 'r') as f:
  app_info = json.load(f)

t = app_info['creon']['token'][0].encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')

token = f'"{t}"'
print(token)
```

The second problem `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType` I think you get it because you haven't set environment variable to the path of your `json` data. I did it like so in my terminal `export app_info=example.json` and it worked properly when I executed the command `python3 example.py` with above python code in the same terminal session with exported environment variable.

Comment: wow... This is exactly the solution for me.
I think you are a super awesome developer.
Thanks for answer !!!

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to print out the quotation marks along with the value, you can do:

```
print('"' + token + '"')
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Similar but didn't work for me.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What does it output?

Comment: token = '"'+app_info['creon']['token']+'"'

print(token)

'TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType'

Comment: Maybe try doing str(app_info['creon']['token'])? Or just add the "'" in the print statement itself as I put in the original answer